# Old domain that was just used for email is not indexing on Google when adding a website

Tags: seo, google-index

So a client has been using a domain for years now just for email.  They recently had me attach a website to that domain about 2 months ago, but it still is not indexed with Google.  I already set everything up with Google Search Console 2 months ago (registered the site, had it crawled, asked it to be indexed, made sure it had a good load time, made sure it was not being blocked by a robots.txt or metatags, etc.) but it still is not showing up. I've also confirmed that it does not appear to be a flagged domain for spam or Blackhat SEO.

Is there anything else I can try to get Google to index it? Also, is this a problem that can be caused by using an old domain like this, or is it likely something else?

FYI: It is indexed on Bing

[EDIT]

Okay I checked back this morning and Google finally indexed the site; however, it is showing up on the 5th page of SERPs in Google even when typing in the exact name of the company, but 1st result on Bing.  Google REALLY is discriminating against this domain (https://rapllclaw.com/)

They are not an SEO client; so, I don't need them showing up 1st, but they should atleast show up on the first page for a proper name query.

Comment: What is the state of the `robots.txt` file?  How are you testing that it is / is not indexed by Google?

Comment: Sounds very strange to me. Maybe there is something blocking Googles crawler. I would look in Search Console to see if there exists any rules in robots.txt an I would also check in Search Console how many indexed urls you have. If it's an apache server look at the .htaccess file to see if there are blocking rules. Personally I would look at the server logfile to see what Google does and if it is trying to crawl the website.

Comment: *...but it still is not indexed with Google...* This is usually not true. What does Google search console report? The expectation that after 2 months a site will appear in the SERPs other than several pages down is common and a mistake. It can take months for a site to be indexed and begin performing as it should in the SERPs. You will have to promote the site to begin gaining any traffic. Cheers!!

Comment: This is strange. Can you PM me the domain? As mentioned by @TopQnA, create profiles on major social networks like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn. Google Plus, Pinterest and Instagram. The motive is to generate referral traffic from these networks. Is the website eligible for creating business listings? If yes, create listings on major business listing websites like YellowPages, StartLocal etc. I can tell more only after seeing the website.

Comment: Testing using Google Search Console; Robots.txt reads: User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Answer (score 1):

What you have done mostly looks good.

Just do this and see in next few days.

Share the links on social media sites, particularly on Google Plus and LinkedIn.

Worth double checking fetch as Google bot and see Google can read the content.

If still doesn't help then you may need to check in detail:

1) Domain history to ensure it didn't get any penalty from Google.

2) Hosting & technical details that nothing different done on the server (ip / bot blocking etc)